# How can I find all of the combinations appear in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, combinations

I have 5 coloumns, each of them contains a lot of different data. Here's an example:

```
A B C D E F  
1 0 1 1 0 1  
2 1 0 0 1 2  
1 2 0 1 2 1  
1 0 1 1 0 1  
...
```

I have to find all of these uniqe combinations. In the example the answer must be 3, because the first row is the same as the last.
I can do it for one column, but when there's more of them, I have no idea, how should I do it?

Comment: Excel can do it for you using the sort tools. https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @CallumDA Excel 2013

Comment: Is there a maximum number of columns or is it always 5, and are the contents numbers in range 0-2, or is that just an example?

Comment: @TomSharpe There are more file, in which I want to do this, and the files have different number of coloumns, from 3 to 12. The contents are not just numbers, I have fields, which contains text, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with VBA. Open the VBA editor and create a new module. Add this code to the module

```
Public Function CountUniqueRows(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")

    With dict
        For Each r In rng.Rows
            s = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r.Value)), "")
            If Not .exists(s) Then
                .Add s, s
            End If
        Next r
    End With

    CountUniqueRows = dict.Count
End Function
```

You can then use the function on the worksheet like this which would return `3` as per your example

```
=CountUniqueRows(A1:F5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your range of data.
On the Data ribbon, select the Remove Duplicates item in the Data Tools section.
Follow the instructions.
Voila!

If you want to keep the original data, you might want to copy and paste to a new sheet and remove the duplicates there.

Comment: The problem is, what I forgot to mention, that the file will be edited, and I'd like it, if the function could calculate the new result immediately, without me doing anything.

Comment: My VBA days are far behind me. For a quick fix, I'd look into recording a macro and wire it up to a button to trigger it manually. I'm sure others can give a solution which is more slick.